# How do I shift the contents of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have an array with the following contents:
a, b, c, d, e, f

I want the result to be:
b, c, d, e, f, a

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) :

```
var t = arr[0];
System.arraycopy(arr, 1, arr, 0, arr.length-1);
arr[arr.length-1] = t;
```

The javadoc specifies this operation is safe :

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the
>   copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through
>   srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length
>   components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied
>   into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination
>   array.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), -1);
```

Comment: @dystroy: I _don't_ end up with an array; this operation would modify `array` in-place.

Comment: Does it really work? http://ideone.com/qmAItu

Comment: Not with an `int[]`, but the OP's array seems to be of `String`s.  It'll work just fine with any `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

try using ArrayList, it has some nice methods which shifts automatically. try

```
myArrayList.add(0,myArrayList.remove(myArrayList.size()-1))
```

Comment: While `ArrayList` is handy, this doesn't *answer* the question of how you do this with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList can do this fast, but you don't need to do this in most cases. Instead, defining a start index is much easier without modifying the content of the array.

For example,

```
int start = 5;

for (int i=start, j=0; j<arr.length; i++, j++) {
    if (i == arr.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    // do something with arr[i]
}
```

copying array is another solution, but if you rotate the array frequently, I suggest not to change the content or creating new arrays, by defining a start index, you can change the start point whenever you want.